# Are tabs vs. spaces discussions acceptable in comments?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

So, we probably all know that the holy war, whether to use tabs or spaces, is a highly subjective thing, and [not really constructive](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57/tabs-versus-spaces-what-is-the-proper-indentation-character-for-everything-in-e) in any situation.

I’m personally of the opinion that everyone is entitled to use whatever they prefer. If they want to use tabs, let them use tabs; if they want to use `n` spaces, let them do that. So my answers are usually indentation-agnostic, or openly give the reader the option to choose whatever they want—it doesn’t really matter.

Now this often leads to comments that one actually should use one or the other, which are rarely helpful and most of the time just annoying and redundant.

So to avoid tabs vs. spaces discussions in the comments, I was thinking about flagging comments that discuss the topic as non-constructive, to prevent a tabs vs. spaces discussion from starting, and to keep my original intent (to *not* say whether to use one or another).

Would such a flag be okay?

*Note:* I’m *not* talking about code submitted in questions or answers to the site. I’m talking about general code you write.

**tl;dr:** Do we want comments on Stack Overflow that start a discussion whether to use tabs or spaces in general when writing code?

Comment: Python code should always use spaces. It's not unconstructive to tell people that. If you don't like it, there's a procedure to try to get the PEP changed. Don't be surprised when Guido laughs at you if you try.

Comment: Spaces accurately display what the code will look like when submitted, tabs don't. There's really no discussion here.

Comment: @Wooble as in "it won't compile" or as in "highly recommended"?

Comment: @Cerbrus how so? I frequently use tabs in my code samples and I don't have display issues.

Comment: @Stijn: as in the official style guide says to only use tabs to be consistent in existing code that used tabs; all new code should use spaces exclusively.

Comment: @Wooble if it doesn't break code, it's a matter of preference. Doesn't matter what the official style guide says.

Comment: Sure, it doesn't matter if you're writing code for yourself in a shack in the woods and don't want to be a part of a community.

Comment: The [MCVE guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) says don't use tabs. Seems to me if this is in the guide provided by SO and people still use tabs, then it is appropriate to ask that tabs be converted to spaces. If someone is not happy with this, then the MCVE guide has to be changed. (Seems to me the question here has reignited the tab vs spaces war. Yay!)

Comment: @Louis Note that I’m *not* talking about submitting questions or answers to the site.

Comment: Hm, I see `tab-size: 4;` has been set on text areas, now. That helps a bit, at least.

Comment: @poke: Then what _are_ you talking about?

Comment: By *indentation-agnostic*, do you mean you're mixing tabs and spaces in the same code snippet? That would be a no-no.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I mean, I simply don’t care whether they want to use tabs or spaces. As long as they are consistent, it doesn’t matter to me.

Comment: @Cerbrus I’m talking about comments to answers or questions that start a discussion whether to use tabs or spaces in general when writing code. It’s not off-topic to discuss whether such unconstructive comments are accepted on SO or not.

Comment: @poke: ooooooh, that makes sense. I completely missed the point of this question, then.

Comment: Truth be said all that really matters in the tabs vs spaces debate is that you follow the guidelines of the project you are coding for. If the project you are working on uses tabs, then use tabs, if they use spaces, use spaces. In fact depending on the age/technology used a project could have files that use tabs (both 4 and 8 spaces) and spaces in different files if older files have not been touched in a long time. And on a website like stack overflow where you are just posting code snippets the difference shouldn't matter as people really shouldn't just copy and paste the answers.

Comment: @Stijn: *Mixing* tabs and spaces can break Python code. In Python 3 that is a syntax error outright. There is a good reason the styleguide tells you to use spaces only.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the info! I don't code in Python, so that's why I asked *as in "it won't compile" or as in "highly recommended"* :)

Comment: @Stijn: if you use *just* tabs it'll *work*, but it is trivially easy to end up with spaces at the start of the line, *then* a tab and it'll look fine in your editor but break somewhere because you  configured your editor to use a 4-space tabstop instead of 8. A common mistake that applies to beginners and experts alike. So you set your editor to expand tabs *always* and never have to worry about the issue again.

Comment: In a makefile you must start a line with a tab, not spaces. However I wish gnu would fix that and spaces would just work anyway. Seems overly fussy to me.

Comment: What am I missing? Are you asking us if it's okay to have discussions about the self-described "holy war" over tabs vs. spaces in the comments? The answer to this question seems self-evident.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, but it’s less about having full discussions but more about commenting in a way that could well result in such a discussion. The votes on this question make me wonder what people actually think about it though; or maybe they just don’t like it that I don’t prefer one over the other… \*sigh\*

Comment: @CodyGray: It looks like it is asking whether flagging is the right approach when tabs-vs-spaces comments are found.

Comment: Well, I downvoted essentially for the reason given in my comment—it seem[ed] like a stupid question. Ben's interpretation makes a bit more sense, though. And other people could have voted for all kinds of reasons. Maybe they thought that this isn't really a problem, so we don't need an official policy. Maybe they thought the answer was self-evident. Who knows? It's got a pretty even split anyway, not too bad for a Meta question. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, such a flag is OK because it fits the very definition of *unconstructive*. There's nothing of value to be gained by having a discussion on tabs versus spaces in the comments on a post.

The only time such a comment would be OK is if it actually breaks the code (won't compile, parser error). Then again, I doubt one would use the wrong indentation in that case.

- One example is Python, [as @MartijnPieters says](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270925/are-tabs-vs-spaces-discussions-acceptable-in-comments?noredirect=1#comment91656_270925):

  > *Mixing* tabs and spaces can break Python code. In Python 3 that is a syntax error outright. There is a good reason the styleguide tells you to use spaces only.

  So although you *are* free to choose, and any decent IDE will reformat code when pasting, it's probably best to err on the side of caution and use spaces for Python code, and to point this out to others.
- Another example is makesfiles, where tabs are mandatory.

Comment: Here you go :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)